# How to avoid IndexError

Tags: python

**A little background:**

I'm writing a small word based maze game starting with a simple maze made of X's, O's and F.

My maze is a list of lists representing the maze itself where X is a wall, O is an open spot and F is the finish line.

I'm trying to write a function that takes the name of the maze and the user's current position and returns a list of all legal moves from that position (N, S, E, or W).

**Here's my practice maze and function.**

```
def get_legal_directions(maze, position):
    x = position[0]
    y = position[1]
    legal = []
    if maze[x-1][y] == 'O' or maze[x-1][y] == 'F':
        legal.append('N')
    if maze[x+1][y] == 'O' or maze[x+1][y] == 'F':
        legal.append('S')  
    if maze[x][y+1] == 'O' or maze[x][y+1] == 'F':
        legal.append('E')
    if maze[x][y-1] == 'O' or maze[x][y-1] == 'F':
        legal.append('W')
    return legal


>>> maze1 = [['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'X', 'F', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']]
>>>
```

input: `get_legal_directions(maze1, (1,1))`

output: `['S']`

so the function appears to work normally here, however when I use the function within another function in order for the user to interact with the maze, I get this:

```
def interact():
    maze = raw_input('Maze File: ')
    x = maze[0]
    y = maze[1]
    pos = (1,1)
    history = [pos]
    while 1:
        print 'You are at position', pos
        command = raw_input('Command: ')
        if command == 'Q':
            com = raw_input('Are you sure you want to quit? [y] or [n]: ')
            if com =='y':
                print 'Thank you for playing - Goodbye!'
                break
            else: continue
        elif command == 'L':
            get_legal_directions(maze, pos)
        else: print 'invalid command'
```

I get the following:

```
>>> interact()

Maze File: maze1

You are at position (1, 1)

Command: L

"   if maze[x-1][y] == 'O' or maze[x-1][y] == 'F':
IndexError: string index out of range"
```

Is there something wrong with the way I've written the if statement or is it something else?  Thanks to anyone who can help.

How can I get the command `L` to call the function `get_legal_directions()`?

Comment: You left out the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes maze a string:

```
maze = raw_input('Maze File: ')
```

Your function expects a list of lists instead.

Comment: This was one of those questions where I was staring at the code, then you answered and I was like "doh".

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you're reading a string.

So you get:

```
maze = 'maze1'
```

instead of what you were probably expecting:

```
maze = maze1 = [['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']...
```

I think you wanted to enter the name of a variable at the prompt and have it turned into the contents of that variable.

So you're reading a string, but you want it to be run as Python code.  You do that using [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval), e.g.:

```
maze = eval(raw_input('Maze File: '))
```

but that's not very safe, because your user could paste any Python code there.

Maybe instead it's better to ask for a maze number, which you could validate:

```
mazes = []
mazes.append([['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'X', 'F', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']])

maze_number = raw_input('Maze Number: ')
maze = mazes[int(maze_number)]
```

Comment: `input` is also considered unsafe as it does an `eval`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are intending to do. You are reading the name of the variable `maze1` and then trying to index it via the variable? This will definitely not work.

One possible solution is to use `eval` as others have pointed out. As you already have understood, eval is not safe and have possible security concerns. Another safer way is to address the globals as a dictionary with your entered string which should be evaluated as a variable.

Here is an example of the changed code

Current

```
maze = raw_input('Maze File: ')
```

Proposed

```
max_try=3
while True:
    try:
        maze = globals()[raw_input('Maze File: ')]
        break
    except KeyError:
        print "Wrong Input"
        max_try-=1
        if not max_try:
            print "Time Out"
            return
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is the problem in the code. OP is reading maze1 as a string and intending it to use it as a variable.

Comment: This is not a clear answer though. You are not showing any examples or references. The other answers at least refer to a line and explain some detail. I shouldn't have to scan between your answer and the OPs code to figure out what you are even referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of `interact()` is:

```
maze = raw_input('Maze File: ')
```

When you did a test run, you typed in "maze1" at the prompt. Therefore `maze` is now set to `"maze1"`.

```
x = maze[0] #x is set to 'm'
y = maze[1] #y is set to 'a'
```

and so on and so forth.

For your test run, change `interact()` so that it accepts the parameter `maze`

```
def interact(mazeData):
    maze = mazeData[:]
    ...
    ...
```

And then call it from the interpreter like so:

```
>>> maze1 = [['X', 'X' ... ... ]]

>>> interact(maze1)
...
...
```

Also keep in mind that the function `get_legal_directions()` will return an index error anytime you use a position that is on the far edge of a maze. Say you give `(10, 5)` as the position and your maze is 10x10. the second if statement will attempt to access `maze[x + 1]` which will be `maze[11]` which is out of the list range. Also, some position arguments (position = 0) you send to the function will give a negative index. This won't generate an error, but it will access the last item in the list, which is not what you want either. You need to add some kind of edge-detection, so that `get_legal_directions()` knows when it is on the edge of the maze and will act accordingly.

Comment: Also, one more thing: There's no reason to use `else: continue` in the main loop in this situation. All the other elif/else blocs will automatically be skipped. If...elif...elif...else blocs in python don't act like switch blocs in c/java. The execution won't "fall through" to the next bloc. The continue is implied.